# Create JSON from five top to bottom related tables

Tags: python, json, database

We run an app that is highly dependent on location. So, we have five models: Country, Province, District, Sector, Cell and Village:

What I want is to generate a JSON that represents them. What I tried aleady is quite long, but I noticed since the structure is the same, one chunk of the module would show my problem.

So, each cell can have multipe villages inside it:

```
cells=database.bring('SELECT id,name FROM batteries_cell WHERE sector_id=' + str(sectorID))
if cells:
    for cell in cells:
        cellID=cell[0]
        cellName=cell[1]
        cell_pro={'id':cellID,'name':cellName,'villages':{}}
        villages=database.bring('SELECT id,name FROM batteries_village WHERE cell_id=' + str(cellID))

        if villages:
            for village in villages:
                villageID=village[0]
                villageName=village[1]
                village_pro={'id':villageID, 'name':villageName}
                cell_pro['villages'].update(village_pro)
```

However, the update just stores the last village for each cell. Any idea what I am doing wrong because I have been trying and deleting different ways to end up in the same result.

UPDATE needed output is:

```
[

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ethiopia",
    "villages": [{

            "vid": 1,
            "vname": "one"
        },

        {

            "vid": 2,
            "vname": "village two"
        }
    ]

},


{

    "id": 2,
    "name": "Sene",
    "villages": [{

            "vid": 3,
            "vname": "third"
        },

        {

            "vid": 4,
            "vname": "fourth"
        }
    ]

     }

  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update keeps overwriting the same keys in the cell_pro villages dict. For example, if village_pro is {'id':'1', 'name':'A'}, then  `cell_pro['villages'].update(village_pro)` will set `cell_pro['villages']['id'] = '1'` and `cell_pro['villages']['name'] = 'A'`. The next village in the loop will overwrite the id and name with something else.

You probably either want to make cell_pro['villages'] into a list or keep it as a dict and add the villages keyed by id:

```
cell_pro['villages'][villageID] = village_pro
```

What format do you want the resulting JSON to be? Maybe you just want:

```
cell_pro['villages'][villageID] = villageName
```

EDITED FOR DESIRED JSON ADDED TO QUESTION:

In the JSON, the villages are in an array. For that we use a list in Python. Note that `cell_pro['villages']` is now a list and we use `append()` to add to it.

```
cells=database.bring('SELECT id,name FROM batteries_cell WHERE sector_id=' + str(sectorID))
if cells:
    for cell in cells:
        cellID=cell[0]
        cellName=cell[1]
        cell_pro={'id':cellID,'name':cellName,'villages':[]}
        villages=database.bring('SELECT id,name FROM batteries_village WHERE cell_id=' + str(cellID))

        if villages:
            for village in villages:
                villageID=village[0]
                villageName=village[1]
                village_pro={'vid':villageID, 'vname':villageName}
                cell_pro['villages'].append(village_pro)
```

TIP: I don't know what database access module you're using but it's generally bad practice to build SQL queries like that because the parameters may not be escaped properly and could lead to SQL injection attacks or errors. Most modules have a way to build query strings with bound parameters that automatically safely escape variables in the query string.

Comment: That would give me a JSON strucutre that is not suitable for the purpose and frankly, am lost on why it is behaving that way when i am in a given cell and updating only the villages key, which happens to be a dictionary. Thanks anyway ivo.

Comment: @NieSelam I added more info to the answer. If that doesn't produce the output you want, let me know what you want the JSON to look like and I'll tell you how to get it.

Comment: lemme add the needed output in the question @ivo

Comment: @NieSelam if this works for you, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Hey @ivo that brings it so much closer yes and in fact, wih a little edit, it worked the way i wanted it all the way from country to villages. Thanks Bro!